# Updating specific xml node with php dom

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'm trying to make php code that updates only required nodes from xml via xpath.

Here's example of php code:

```
    // get variables
    $toimipaikka = $_GET["toimipaikka"]; 
    $ohje = $_GET["ohje"];
    $uusohje = $_GET["uusohje"];

    //load file
    $ohjeet = new DomDocument;
    $ohjeet->load('genesis.xml');
    $xpolku = new DomXpath($ohjeet);

    // find specific nodes and update 
foreach ($xpolku->query('//ohjeet/ohje[@toimipaikka="' . $toimipaikka . '"]/osa[@ohj="' . $ohje . '"]') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($node, $uusohje);
}
      // save xml file
      file_put_contents('genesis.xml',$ohjeet->saveXML());
```

And here is example of xml file:

```
<ohjeet> 
    <ohje toimipaikka="kaikki"> 
        <osa ohj="ohj_1101"><![CDATA[
        <a href="apple">link link link<a>
        ]]></osa>
    </ohje>
    <ohje toimipaikka="labra"> 
        <osa ohj="ohj_110"><![CDATA[
        <li>text text text</li>
        ]]></osa>
        <osa ohj="ohj_110"><![CDATA[
        <li>text text text</li>
        ]]></osa>
    </ohje>
</ohjeet>
```

It opens the file and saves it but no changes are made. Any advises? I'm pretty sure the problem is in the foreach loop but just cant find it.

Comment: 2nd arg of [`replaceChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) supposed to be an instance of `DOMNode`

Comment: and change order of arguments: ` $new = $ohjeet->createElement('new', 'This is a new element!');
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($new, $node);`